# File name as variable+.txt

Tags: php, variables, filenames

```
session_start();
$user = $_SESSION['username'];

if( isset($_POST['subm_btn']) ) { 
incrementClickCount();
}
function getClickCount()
{
return (int)file_get_contents($user.".txt");
 }
 function incrementClickCount()
 { $count = getClickCount() + 1;
 file_put_contents($user.".txt", $count);
  }
```

User register on my site, then he click on button (name="subm_btn"). I want count clicks and add number of clicks in file with name "username.txt"

Comment: How should this script work and what isn't working for you?

Comment: Note: the way you currently have this written has the potential to be problematic.  If I can somehow make my username, say `/var/www/secret_stuff`, that would be bad.  Sanitize those strings :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for something like this:

```
$file=$user.'.txt';
incrementClickCount($file);

function incrementClickCount($file){ 
  $count = getClickCount($file) + 1;
  file_put_contents($file, $count);
}

function getClickCount($file) {
   return (int)file_get_contents($file);
}
```

If you want the variable to be available inside a function you either make it global or pass it as an argument (which is better).

Answer (score 0):

You define `$user`, and then access `$user1`.  That would be my guess as to why it doesn't work.  Also, using `$file` might be a better idea anyway.